# Non-buffered output to response in Web2py

Tags: web2py, flush, output-buffering

Is it possible in Web2py to write data to response as it becomes available?
For example I have a very long-running function that writes its progress to response.
I want its output to appear immediately when it's printed, not when the whole function finishes.

Answer (score 2):

check out this simple example I wrote, it may help, works for me

```
#The process to run (print the tablenames)
def process(db):
    for tablename in db.tables:
        for i in range(int(1e5)): pass #Simulate long task for the table
        yield "%s is ready! <br/>" % tablename #Table result

#You call this
def test():
    return process(db) #Returning the generator streams the individual results
```